# C conditional checks with regards to fgets

Tags: c, conditional-statements, fgets

I am having some issues with my code I am trying to create a terminal App that outputs certain messages if the users input is invalid

Examples of invalid input (where the word "Incorrect!\n" is printed out include

1. `"lunch"`
2. `"lunch  "`
3. `" lunch"`
4. `"lunchfent "`

Now an Incorrect value is any input that does not follow the `"lunch XXX"` schema with one space separating them

An incorrect value can be,

```
"lunch asdasdasd"
"lunch asdasdasdasdasd"
"lunch A "
"lunch 123"
```

Now my code C outputs the correct stuff for the following 3

1. `"lunch"`
2. `"lunch  "`
3. `" lunch"`

However for `"lunchment A1"` It outputs `Invalid`, but that is because I have hardcoded it (see 3rd else if statement)

My first question is

**how do I go about handling cases where `lunch` appears as a substring without hardcoding**

Secondly,

For cases such as `"lunch averylongstringfollowedbywhitespaceandacharacter Z1"`

My code outputs `"Incorrect Value"`

But since there is 3 spaces and the input string is larger than `9` we should output `"Incorrect"` instead of `"Incorrect Value"`

Here is my reproducible code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int sanitize_input(const char buffer[]);
char Buffer[11];
int count_spaces();
int valid_command_entered = 0;
int lunch_command_entered = 0;

int main()
{
    while (fgets(Buffer, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (Buffer[strlen(Buffer) - 1] == '\n') {
            Buffer[strlen(Buffer) - 1] = '\0';  // Remove newline
        } else {
            int c;

            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
            }                           // Clear input buffer
        }

        if (strlen(Buffer) > 10) {
            printf("Invalid!\n");
            valid_command_entered = 0;
            continue;
        }

        if (strstr(Buffer, "lunch") != NULL) {
            valid_command_entered = 1;
            lunch_command_entered = 1;
            sanitize_input(Buffer);
            fflush(stdin);
        }

        if (valid_command_entered == 0) {
            printf("Incorrect!\n");
        }
    }
}

int sanitize_input(const char buffer[])
{
    if (buffer[0] != 'l' && count_spaces() >= 1) {
        printf("Incorrect!\n");
    }
    else if (count_spaces() > 1) {
        printf("Incorrect!\n");
    }
    else if (strlen(buffer) >= 8 && strlen(buffer) <= 10 &&
        !strncmp(buffer, "lunchment ", 10)) {
        printf("Incorrect!\n");
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    else if (strcmp("lunch ", buffer) == 0) {
        printf("Incorrect!\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp("lunch", buffer) == 0) {
        printf("Incorrect!\n");
    }
    else if (count_spaces() == 0) {
        printf("Incorrect!\n");
    }
    if (count_spaces() == 1 && strcmp(buffer, "lunch ") > 0 &&
        strlen(Buffer) >= 8 && buffer[5] == ' ') {
        char *split_by = " ";
        char *token;
        char bufferCopy[11];

        strcpy(bufferCopy, Buffer);
        token = strtok(bufferCopy, split_by);
        int idx = 0;

        while (token != NULL) {
            idx++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            if (idx == 1) {
                if (strlen(token) > 3 && lunch_command_entered == 1) {
                    printf("Incorrect value\n");
                }
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
}

int count_spaces()
{
    int size = sizeof(Buffer);
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (Buffer[i] == ' ') {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but please note that passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: With an 11-character buffer, `strlen(buffer) <= 10` will always be true (assuming its properly null-terminated, which `fgets` guarantees).

Comment: Also, the string `"lunchment"` is *nine* characters long. Why do you want to compare ten characters?

Comment: @DeepAlgo212345,  What is wrong with `"lunch 123"`?  Why is that not following the `"lunch XXX"` schema?

Comment: That has digits in it it must be in the format of lunch XYZ

X = upper case alphabet
Y = digit
z= digit

The last Z is optional

Answer (score 1):

Tackle this problem in steps:

- Read the line into a generous buffer.  Fail very long lines.

```
#define EXEPCTED_SIZE sizeof("Lunch XXX") /* 10 */  
char buffer[EXEPCTED_SIZE * 2];  // Be generous, read in up to 2x

if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_EndOfFile();
}
// Find the length.
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
if (len + 1 == sizeof buffer && buffer[len - 1] != '\n') {
  // Line is much too long to meet goal and more remains to be read.
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    ;
  } 
  return No_Find;
}
```

- Parse carefully candidate lines.

Consider using `"%n"` to record the offset of scanning, if it got that far.

```
else {
  // format of lunch XYZ X = upper case alphabet Y = digit z= digit The last Z is optional
  // Look for target_substring  ("Lunch")
  size_t target_length = strlen(target_substring);
  if (memcmp(buffer, target_substring, target_length)) {
    return No_Find;
  }
  char space[2];
  char upletter[2];
  char digit[3];
  int n = 0;
  char *rest = buffer + target_length;
  sscanf(rest, "%1[ ]%1[A-Z]%2[0-9]%n", space, upletter, digits, &n);
  
  if (n == 0 || (rest[n] != '\n' && rest[n] != 0)) {
    return No_Find;
  }
  return Find;
}
```

Comment: technically `%1[A-Z]` may match characters that are not uppercase letters if these are not contiguous in the character set, such as `EBCDIC` but such problems are unlikely nowadays.

Comment: Also the code could be simplified by suppressing assignment with `sscanf(rest, "%*1[ ]%*1[A-Z]%*2[0-9]%n", &n);`

Comment: @chqrlie Agree about suppressing `space`, yet OP likely wants to read `upletter[]` and `digit[3]`.

Comment: @chqrlie I wonder if `char XXX[3]; sscanf(rest, "%*1[ ]%1[A-Z]%2[0-9]%n", space, XXX, XXX + 1, &n);` would be OK. Hmmm - ( I think not as there is an implied `restrict` on the `...` arguments.)

Comment: `XXX` should have a minimum length of `4`, and regarding the implied `restrict`, I'm not sure there is such a thing, there is no mention of it in the Standard. The C Standard specifies that *The `fscanf` function executes each directive of the format in turn* so the next `%[...]`  directives does not interfere with the previous one and the description of the directives leaves no space for interpretation.  It would take a perverse implementation to make this conversion have unexpected behavior (IMHO).

Comment: @chqrlie Yes `char XXX[4];` of course.